# Laravel How to use button from controller into blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm using ajax to pass data from controller and the controller pass the response html to the ajax, this html contains a button, I want to use this button inside the blade again in jquery function, this button contains data and wants to use this data to pass it again to another controller function

in controller

```
  <button class="remove_this OrderItem_action Button_root" data-id="'.$Product->rowId.'" data-price="'.$Product->price*$Product->qty.'" data-qty="'.$Product->qty.'" type="submit">Remove</button>
```

I want to implement this function using the passed button, like this example but it doesnt work, how can I do this

```
<script>
 $(function(){ 
$('.remove_this').on("click", function () { 
 alert('just test');
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this problem just use this

```
       $(document).on('click','.remove_this', function () { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data like `$Product->rowId` to the blade with `return view('index')->with($Product)`. Then you can call your variable $Product in your blade like `{{ $Product->id }}`

In your situation:

> Controller

```
return view('index')->with($Product)
```

> Blade

```
<button class="remove_this OrderItem_action Button_root" data-id="{{ $Product->rowId }}" data-price="{{ $Product->price*$Product->qty }}" data-qty="{{ $Product->qty }}" type="submit">Remove</button>
```

then you can pass your jquery in your blade using the `@push()` method

```
@push('scripts')
  <script>
      $(function(){ 
          $('.remove_this').on("click", function () { 
              alert('just test');
          });
      });
  </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: I'm using ajax and what you said can't work with ajax, this will refresh the page!!!!!!!!

Comment: Check this one: [pass-data-from-ajax-to-controller-in-laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pass-data-from-ajax-to-controller-in-laravel). Maybe will solves your problem.

Comment: are you understanding me? I dont have problem with returning data!! the problem after return this data is to use one of the button from this data to use it for implementing something

Comment: Then you need to be more clear.. `I want to implement this function using the passed button, like this example but it doesn't work, how can I do this`

what does not work exactly.. Do you get console error logs or something?

Comment: the same problem here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486393/laravel-delete-from-shopping-cart-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment89941882_51486393

Comment: I think the answer is posted in the post you mentioned: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486393/laravel-delete-from-shopping-cart-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment89941882_51486393). use the ajax method and change the type to POST if you want to post the data. Pass it to the url you want, in the routes, you can send that url to a controller and there you can request the data. If this is not what you meant, then I don't know what you try to do, your question has to be more specific then.