# Laravel delete from Shopping Cart using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I want to delete from Cart using Ajax, I'm adding with no problem but how can I delete without refresh the page while I have many items and may I need to delete one by one, Im passing the html from delete function in controller to view blade, so when Im at the page for the first time it deletes but after delete of one item cant delete more

```
 <script>
 $(function(){ 
  $('.remove_item').on("click", function () { 
  var id = $(this).data('id'); 
  $.ajax({
         type: 'DELETE',
         url: "cart/"+ id,  
         data: {'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
         success: function (data) {
           $('#cart_product').html(data);        
         }               
    });
   });
 });
</script>
```

delete in controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
     Cart::remove($id);
     $products = Cart::content();
     foreach($products as $Product){

     echo '<div class="OrderItem_root styles_base styles_spacing-base">
           <div class="OrderItem_quantity styles_just-right styles_base 
           styles_spacing-base">'.$Product->qty.'</div>
           <div class="OrderItem_container">
           <div class="OrderItem_category"></div>
           <div class="OrderItem_itemHeader">
           <div id="titletest" class="OrderItem_name styles_just-right styles_base styles_spacing-base">'.$Product->name.'</div>
           <div id="cartprice" class="OrderItem_total">$'.$Product->price*$Product->qty.'</div>
            <input id="mycartprice" type="text" name="mycartprice" value="'.$Product->price.'"  hidden="">
         </div>
        <div>
        </div>
      <div>
     <button class="remove_item OrderItem_action Button_root" data-id="'.$Product->rowId.'" data-price="'.$Product->price*$Product->qty.'" data-qty="'.$Product->qty.'" type="submit">Remove</button>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>';
   }
 }
```

Comment: Use a proper error handling pattern in ajax call

Comment: I don't have error its all about how to use button where its in the controller, so after the first delete the controller pass json html to ajax with the new remove button even it has the same id or class but can't use it because I already loaded the blade before execute the javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your element is dynamically updated and you should attach event again.
use this code instead:

```
     <script>
     $(function(){ 
 $(document).on('click','.remove_item', function () { 
      var id = $(this).data('id'); 
      $.ajax({
             type: 'DELETE',
             url: "cart/"+ id,  
             data: {'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
             success: function (data) {
               $('#cart_product').html(data);        
             }               
        });
       });
     });
    </script>
```